# ActionScript 3's "move" keyword: does it exist?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, keyword, move

I'm programming in Flash and I notice every time I use the word "move", it lights up blue as if it were a keyword. I can't find any documentation on it, so I've just been avoiding using the word for any functions. Is there a built-in "move" function? Is it a keyword for something else? What does it do?

edit: I'm using Flash CS 5.5 for an IDE.

Comment: "move" is not a keyword in AS3. If you use the Flex framework the `UIComponent` defines a `move()` method as well as dispatches a "move" event.  You might want to specify which IDE you use to write your Flash code. Flash Builder, for example, does not color "move" in blue as a keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html) there is no `move` keyword in ActionScript 3. I'd check your editor's syntax highlighting settings and ensure that it is set to AS3. It wasn't a keyword in AS2 either, at least according to [this book](http://openbook.galileodesign.de/actionscript/actionscript_1_05_002.htm#t2t36).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a doc about a `Move` class for [Flex AS3](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/effects/Move.html).